# Opening byte[] as a file without actually saving it as a file first

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, ms-word, ms-office

What is the best way to open a Word file that was stored as a byte[] in a database?

I have to store some documents in an Access database - Word files, 2003 and up - on an application that is strictly run off of a CD. Unfortunately they have to be in the database and can't be stored loose in folders. I'm storing them as an OLE object, and I can read and write them just fine as a byte[].

However, I don't know the best way of getting these documents back open in Word. Right now I'm using a FileStream to recreate the file in somewhere and then shooting off a `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename)` to get it to open. This is going to be used on government computers which can have some funky security rules sometimes, so I don't know if this is the best way.

Is it possible to open a file previously stored as a byte[] without using any intermediary file saved to the hard drive? I know they'll at least have Word 2003, so I'm open to using the Word interop.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: There is no other option.  You are doing it right.

Comment: Question: Are the opened files meant for editing, or will they be read-only? If the former, your security concerns are going to be wasted on the user anyway. If the latter, do you really need to have them opened in Word? If you're simply displaying word documents, you could consider placing a portable openoffice on the disc, modify it to suit this task - though I'm not sure how much work that'd be.

Comment: They're read-only and should be opened with whatever the computer opens .doc/.docx files with. I think including my own reader like a portable openoffice would be pretty unpopular with the people opening the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt you're going to be able to feed Word a file in memory without saving it to at least a RAMDisk or something wild like that.

Why not use the system temp folder or the GetTempFile() method to write the byte array to a file just before opening it using Word and then cleaning up the temp files when you're done?

```
  string fullPathToATempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
// or
  string tempDirPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```