# Parse Byte[] to File without saving it

Tags: c#, .net

I am querying a web service (External system) which returns me a byte[]. This byte[] is a csv file, I am saving the byte[] to a temp location as a csv and then parsing the csv file to the database.

Is it possible to directly read the byte[] and instead of saving the file to a temp location, store it in memory and parse the file contents to the database?

I looked at [Opening byte[] as a file without actually saving it as a file first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199674/opening-byte-as-a-file-without-actually-saving-it-as-a-file-first) not sure if things have changed now? Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to convert the byte[] to a string? If so, you can just call Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) - if the file is UTF8 encoded that is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not very easy to find but there is a CSV parser in standard.

```
    public void HandleMycontent(byte[] content)
    {
        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(content))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                using (var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(reader))
                {
                    //parse my csv here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there nothing equallent of Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser in Microsoft.Csharp ? Or do I really have to use a reference to VisualBasic?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to use the reference to VisualBasic, I agree the location it's a bit strange but it's still part of the framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MemoryStream` class instead of a `FileStream`:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(yourByteArray);
```

Comment: Probably want that wrapped in a `StreamReader` for parsing the CSV with `ReadLine`, at a minimum.

Comment: @GrantThomas CSV is more subtle than just newlines, technically; I would advise a dedicated CSV parser...

Comment: @MarcGravell Surely, I agree; was just highlighting that this answer alone gives the OP no more than a different way of managing his bytes and no real value toward accomplishing the end result. Even giving lines of text would be more of an achievement...

Comment: @GrantThomas: As I understood the OP, he already has everything in place to read the file. I assume that code operates on a stream. In that case, he can simply drop in that memory stream at the place he previously had the file stream. Whether he wraps it or not is the same in both cases, that's why I ommitted it. And I disagree with your conclusion that the answer doesn't help him.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth To say it won't help the OP at all is perhaps an overstatement. I guess it's one of those situations where we see a question differently; I didn't read into it the same way you did.

Answer (score 1):

The related question you link to is about loading it **in Word**. That is very different to just parsing it locally. In that case, just hook it up to a `MemoryStream` and [`CsvReader` (external link)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader): job done:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(theData))
using(var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
using(var reader = new CsvReader(sr)) {
    // read the data...
}
```

Comment: public CsvReader(System.IO.TextReader reader, bool hasHeaders)
    Member of LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.CsvReader

Summary:
Initializes a new instance of the CsvReader class.

Parameters:
reader: A TextReader pointing to the CSV file.
hasHeaders: true if field names are located on the first non commented line, otherwise, false.

Exceptions:
ArgumentNullException: reader is a null.
ArgumentException: Cannot read from reader.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure about this since on the other side object should be serialized following the same logic, but you can give this a try:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
memoryStream.Write(serializedInstance, 0, serializedInstance.Length);
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
string deserializedInstance = (string)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
```